# C++ Error error: invalid types 'double [10][10][double]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am trying to generate a grid by looping from 0 to 1 in increments of 0.1. The code runs fine when I am incrementing with an integer eg from 0 to 10 in increments of 1 but I am not able to understand whats wrong with this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

double u[10][10];
double dx=0.1, i, j;

for(i=0;i<=1;i+=dx)
for(j=0;j<=1;j+=dx)
{
    u[i][j]=i; // this line gives an error
}
}
```

Comment: And your question is, exactly what? `i` and `j` are doubles. You can't index an array with a double. Next question, please... P.S. The shown code has another bug too. Both loops use `i`.

Comment: Array indexes are integers. You can't use doubles in place of integers to index arrays. Clearly, you can't declare `double dx=0.1, i, j;`. The error message you included in the title tells you that in plain language. Learn to read the words in the message - they have meaning. They're not there to just take up space on your screen.

Comment: Fixed that, the second loop is j. If I increment using integer, the loop will run forever. i+dx=i for integer.

Comment: @Nick Instead of loop from 0 to 1 by 0.1, you can loop from 0 to 10 by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that you are trying to access indexes of your array by using a double, such as 0.3. Since array indexes are integers, trying to access a double index will result in an error.

I think this is what you were trying to do, so try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double u[11][11];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
            u[i][j] = (double)(i / 10.0);

}
```

So instead of trying to access u at [0.3][0.3], we're accessing u at [3][3] and just changing i to a double in inputting i into the array.